# Smtp - configuration & set up?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, smtp, lamp, email-verification

I have a php script, for sharing pictures,
that seems to offer a configuration of smtp.

At least this is what it looks like in the dashboard:

[smtp settings in dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Iath.png)

However, I don't know what to type in there.

What is the smtp host, what is the username / password...

I have not setup anything alike in my server.

I am using aws ec2, amazon linux 2, lamp server.

Btw I have to say, that right now anyone can register on my website, without having to confirm his mail adress (there is no error; its just as if there is no verification process).

Thanks for any help here!

Andy

Comment: You need an SMTP server to send emails. Since you're using AWS, you can set up AWS SES as an SMTP server.

Comment: Thanks. Will do this. - However, think I will have to edit my phpMyAdmin then. As I saw some tutorials on youtube, where you have to set it up there.

Comment: SMTP has nothing to do with PhpMyAdmin. It just takes care of sending emails: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol